# Observer pattern with JSF/PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, observer-pattern

Is there a recommended way of implementing the Observer pattern in JSF, i.e. forcing a UI update from the Java bean?

I've taken a look at PrimePush, but none of their ShowCase examples seem to work with my browsers (e.g. FF 19.0), which is why I shied away from it.

I am currently using a PrimeFaces poll to update the respective components in a regular interval. I was thinking about reducing the poll’s interval to "1" and having its action method block until the server is ready to push. Is that a good idea or will such long-running requests be canceled at some point?

```html
<p:poll interval="15" listener="#{fileBucket.keepAlive}" update=":download:files :expiryDateValue" oncomplete="updatePageIsValidForValue();" />
```

Comment: Maybe the problem you had is how you implemented the push. I've tested it in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9. What browsers are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The main browser I'm interested in is Firefox 19.0. I haven't implemented Push in my solution yet, I was actually talking about their showcase samples.

Comment: Well, you can open the [FacesMessage example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/facesmessage.jsf) in Firefox 19 and in Chrome (or another browser) in the same machine, then send a message from the non-Firefox browser and see the answer in your Firefox, it should give you the expected behavior (I've tested it before posting this comment). Btw I'm using Firefox 19 (I didn't realized until now)

Comment: Just tested it with Firefox 19.0 and Google Chrome 25.0. The message isn't displayed in either of the browser windows (not even in the one originally sending it). I'm not receiving any error messages in the FireBug console, either. Any pitfalls that I should be aware of?

Comment: I think I found the problem with PrimePush. The showcase examples run PrimePush over port 8080 for some reason, which is blocked in our environment. I'll be trying to implement my own prime push example then.

Comment: Maybe you're running another process over port 8080 (Tomcat, GlassFish, JBoss maybe?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking action in poll would basicaly be a hand-crafted push and I would advise against it, you will most likely run into many problems. Polling is safer and more portable but if this is not enough you should try one of the existing push implementations like PrimePush.

Comment: Thx! I've experimented with PrimePush, now that the port problem is solved, and while it worked fine in my test environment, I currently won't get permission to introduce it to the project just for the sake of this one page. So I'll stick with the polling approach.